# Is there a way to parse the HTTP response in order to create constants based on the response.length?

Tags: javascript, http, cypress, response

Using cypress, i'm trying to parse the http response and in this case, create constants based on the number of objects in the array.

This is the response:
[HTTP RESPONSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHqiG.png)

I don't know if this is the best practice but i'd like to "auto create" a lot of constants based on response.body.data.length and response.body.data.customer from each object of the array, something like this:

```
const customerId0 = response.body.data[0].customer // the name of the constant should be based on the array length.
```

The code is now:

```
describe("UC01 - IMPORT FROM ASAAS", function () {
it("UC01.01 - GET SUBSCRIPTIONS", function () {
    cy.request({
        method: "GET",
        url: Cypress.env("asaasApi") + "/api/v3/subscriptions?offset0&limit=100",
        headers: {
            access_token: asaasToken,
        },
    }).then((response) => {
        const subscriptions = response.body.data;
        console.log(subscriptions.length);
        const customerId0 = subscriptions[0].customer;
        cy.log({ customerId0 });
        expect(subscriptions).to.not.equal(undefined);
        expect(subscriptions).to.not.equal(null);
        cy.writeFile("cypress/json/subscriptions.json", subscriptions);
    });
});
```

});

Comment: You cannot (and should not) dynamically create and name variables.

Comment: Do you know why? (i'm just starting)

Comment: Because variables are declared in code, and code that is executed is static. A programmer wouldn't understand code that dynamically creates variables, because one would never know where a variable came from or which variable an identifier was bound to. Use arrays and objects instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use dynamic names for `const` declared variables as far as I know.

The closest you might get is to extract an array of customers and use indexing on it

```js
cy.request({
  ...
}).then((response) => {
  const subscriptions = response.body.data;
  const customerIds = subscriptions.map(subscription => subscription.customer);
  cy.log(customerIds[0])
  cy.wrap(customerIds).as('customerIds')  // save for use outside response block
})

// later in the test

cy.get('@customerIds').then(customerIds=> {
  expect(customerIds[0])...
```